# Java game development - Look and shoot at mouse coordinates

Tags: java, mouse, angle

I'm going to make a game where you run around with a character, seen from above. But the problem is how do I make the character look at the mouse all the time? And how do I calculate the angle so that I can shoot towards the mouse(where I'm currently looking). I guess you have to play around with trigonometry and stuff like that to get angles, but I really don't know how.

I'm pretty good at math, so I might figure it out if you guys give me some help.

And sorry for my eventually bad english, I'm swedish :)

Thanks,
Alexandberg

Comment: I think you answered your own question...use trig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double angle = Math.atan2(yMouse-yChar, xMouse-xChar);
```

Comment: That didn't work very well I think. I just got numbers from -3 to 3, but I don't know what to do with them. I thought the angles would be more like 0-360.

Comment: It's -pi to pi actually because it's in radians. To convert it to degrees, call Math.toDegrees()

Comment: Thanks, the angles are working now (except for the angles are between -180 and 180, but I can fix that). The problem is, how do I draw a line that goes from the player through the mouse (it continues after it hits the mouse location). Right now I got the distance between the player and the mouse point and the angle.

Answer (score 1):

as you said a big hint can be found in trig

```
Point pl = getCharacterLox();
Point mouse = getMouseLoc();
double cos = (mouse.getX()-pl.getX());
double sin = (mouse.getY()-pl.getY());
cos/=Math.hypot(cos,sin);//normalize 
double angle = Math.copySign(Math.acos(cos),sin);
```

I used a little trick here in the last line: acos is between 0 and PI but if sin is negative it should be negated, if sin is 0 it will evaluate to +0.0 and angle will be 0 or PI regardless

Comment: Thanks alot, I think I got it now.

Edit: When I try to print the angle to check if it works it's just between 0-3 (aprox). How do I get the angle out of that? Because I don't see how I'm going to use the angle right now to do anything.